# The word play in The Association song Along Comes Mary

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics, jokes, word-play, pun

Does the phrase “Sweet as a punch” in the context of this song mean sweet as a drink AND “pleasant” as a strike with the fist? Do I understand the word play in Along Comes Mary by The Association correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be? I looked up the lyrics to the song you mentioned and my first assumption would be that the narrator is saying his cup in its empty state is somehow just as good as the drink that used to be in it. But I could easily be wrong. Lyric interpretation can be a tricky thing and sometimes people argue over what is meant by any one line in a song.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, @MaryIs! I agree that there could be numerous interpretations and thought it might be interesting to hear the opinion of other English-speakers!